# Need help writing prop to blak :: Sudoku → [Pos] (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, ghci

i stumbled over this thread [Haskell List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823016/haskell-list-comprehension) And am now trying to write a prop for it that states that all cells in this function actually are blank, but have only gotten this far with the following error message when trying to compile it.

```
{-
Property that states that all cells in the blanks list are actually blank
-}
prop_blank_pos :: Sudoku →  Bool
prop_blank_pos sud = (rows sud) !! (fst pair) !! (snd pair) ≡ Nothing
   where pair = blanks sud
```

could't match expected type '(a, b)' against inferred type '[Pos]'
in the first argument 'fst'' namley pair and second of '(!!)' namley fst pair
in the first argument of '(rows) bankey ('rows sud)'

Edit

My question is, the list that i get from blanks is a list [Pos] containing [(Nothing,Nothing),(Nothing,Nothing)...etc].

I want to check that all tuples both elements actually are "Nothing", i.e all Elements in the [Pos] are (Nothing,Nothing). How can I check this, Can anybody write a code sample, Im not good at the haskell syntax.

Edit 2

Here is an example of a soduku

```
example :: Sudoku
  example =
    Sudoku
      [ [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing,Nothing,Just 7, Just 1, Just 2, Nothing,Nothing]
      , [Nothing,Just 5, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 1, Just 8, Nothing]
      , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 9, Just 2, Nothing,Just 4, Just 7, Nothing,Nothing]
      , [Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 1, Just 3, Nothing,Just 2, Just 8]
      , [Just 4, Nothing,Nothing,Just 5, Nothing,Just 2, Nothing,Nothing,Just 9]
      , [Just 2, Just 7, Nothing,Just 4, Just 6, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
      , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 5, Just 3, Nothing,Just 8, Just 9, Nothing,Nothing]
      , [Nothing,Just 8, Just 3, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 6, Nothing]
      , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 7, Just 6, Just 9, Nothing,Nothing,Just 4, Just 3]
      ]
```

Edit 3
Here is how sudoku is defined

```
data Sudoku = Sudoku { rows :: [[Maybe Int]] }
 deriving ( Show, Eq )
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you need exactly, so I'll tell you what the compiler error means.

`fst` operates on tuples `(a, b)`, but you're giving it a `[Pos]`.

Either make sure `pair` returns a tuple, or use the list functions for fetching the first and second element, e.g. `head pair` for the first and `pair !! 1` for the second element.

It seems to me you want `pair` to return a tuple, but that isn't really happening. `blanks sud` is returning a list of `Pos`.

---

Edit: okay, so a `Pos` is a tuple, and you want to check if a `[Pos]` contains only tuples which are equal to `(Nothing, Nothing)`.

As Dave said in the comments, to do this, you could try something like `all (==(Nothing, Nothing)) the_list`. This returns `True` if all elements of `the_list` are equal to `(Nothing, Nothing)`.

```
prop_blank_pos :: Sudoku -> Bool
prop_blank_pos sud = all (==(Nothing, Nothing)) (blanks sud)
```

Comment: Possibly `pair` is a list of tuples. Johan would then need to use `all` to check the condition for all elements of the list.

Comment: When I do as liszt is suggesting I get the following error message 

Couldn't match the expected type '[(Maybe a, Maybe a1)]'
Inferred type [Pos]
In the second argument of 'all', namley (blanks sud)'
In the expression  all (≡(Nothing, Nothing)) (blanks sud)

Any one have an idea how to please the compiler to get this to work? :)

Comment: After loading your module in ghci, what is the output of `:i Pos`? What is the output of `:t blanks`? The compiler is telling you `Pos` can never be `(Nothing, Nothing)`, so it makes no sense comparing it to those values.

Comment: :i Pos = "type Pos = (Int, Int)"
:t blanks = blanks :: Sudoku ->[Pos]

So I see, so how can i look what is stored at the position Pos(0,3) == Nothing?

Comment: A `Pos` is, then, only a pair of `Int`, and an `Int` can never be `Nothing`. It can only be a number. Therefore, comparing an `Int` to `Nothing` makes no sense to GHC. `blanks` returns a list of positions. To find out what is at that location on the sudoku grid, you need to combine this position (pair of `Int`s) with the grid itself. The way you combine these two depends on the way you've defined your grid, which is something you haven't told us.

Comment: Assuming your grid `sud` is defined as a list of lists of `Int` (in other words, `[[Int]]`, and assuming you've chosen the number zero to define a location on the grid as blank, you can check to see if all locations on the grid are blank using, say, this: `all (\\(x, y) -> sud !! y !! x == 0) (blanks sud)`. For each `(x, y)` pair in `blanks sud`, we check if that location on the grid is equal to zero.

Comment: I've just noticed you've edited the post. If `sud` is `[[Maybe Int]]`, then simply substitute the `== 0` in my previous comment with `== Nothing`.

Comment: Im sorry, im still don't get it to work, I changed it like this

prop_blank_pos :: Sudoku →  Bool
prop_blank_pos sud = all (\(x, y) -> sud !! y !! x == Nothing) (blanks sud)

And this time the compiler says
"Couldnt match expected type [a] against inferred type 'Soduku' In the first argument of '(!!)' namley 'sud', 'sud !! y', 'sud !! y !! x'

Comment: This is because `sud` isn't `[[Maybe Int]]`, but rather `Sudoku { rows :: [[Maybe Int]] }`. You need to grab an element from the `rows` attribute of `sud`, not from `sud` itself. So, instead of `sud !! y !! x`, do `rows sud !! y !! x`. (Oh, and next time, put all of this info up front. ^^)

Comment: You have been such a help. Now just one last question, why does this function evaluate to false(? It means that blanks doesn't work correctly?

Comment: I would think so. `blanks` seems to return at least one position which doesn't contain `Nothing`. Another source of error could be `!! y !! x`, which should be reversed to `!! x !! y`, depending on the way your code works.

Comment: It was the later one that caused it to evalute to false, thank you so much for your help :)(Ps. I don't know how to mark this thread as solved but perhaps the moderator can do it for me)